# Dropping new column into table and want to fill with new data via case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a basic table with customer, region, sales person, sales item.  Sales items are abbreviated, for example, TENN is input for Tennis Shoes.  In the new column, call it SALES2, I want to correct with different names.  This is what I have so far, but it's not working

```
ALTER TABLE SALES
DROP COLUMN SALES2 varchar(25) AFTER Sales Item;
UPDATE SALES
SET SALES2= CASE
(
WHEN Sales Item = 'TENN' THEN 'Tennis Shoes'
WHEN Sales Item = 'PJs' then 'Pajamas'
ELSE = Other
)
END
```

Here's what I'm looking for in end result
[image]

Comment: Do you want to DROP a column? or UPDATE your table? or both?

Comment: both - drop a new column, so I can fill it with different names

Comment: In your code `DROP COLUMN SALES2` you are trying to drop Sales2 column, but in your expected results it's exists, Then you are trying to update that column too. I couldn't understand what are you trying to say

Comment: Drop a new column??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, you want to `add` a column, not `drop` it (which means removing it):

```
ALTER TABLE SALES
ADD COLUMN SALES2 varchar(25) AFTER Sales Item;
```

Second, your `case` syntax is wrong - you should remove the `=` after the `else`, use single quotes to denote that string and remove the parenthesis:

```
UPDATE SALES
SET SALES2= CASE
WHEN [Sales Item] = 'TENN' THEN 'Tennis Shoes'
WHEN [Sales Item] = 'PJs'  THEN 'Pajamas'
ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Comment: Im using my sql server V8 and it says that this is the wrong syntax for version - any ideas or know what may be the difference here?

Comment: @newbie most probably the issue was I forgot to escape the column name with a space in it. See my edited answer.

Comment: I tried that - I get this error 'Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Sales Item] = ’Tenn’ THEN 'Tennis Shoes' WHEN [Sales Item] = ’PJs’ THEN 'Pajamas'

Comment: @newbie OK, that explains it. You're using [tag:mysql], but you tagged the question with [tag:sql-server]. Those are different databases, and unfortunately, the finer points of the syntax are not interchangeable. You can escape column names with backticks in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed column!  Then, no update is necessary.  The column simply that the value as computed:

```
ALTER TABLE SALES
    ADD SALES2 AS (CASE WHEN SalesItem = 'TENN' THEN 'Tennis Shoes'
                        WHEN SalesItem = 'PJs'  THEN 'Pajamas'
                        ELSE 'Other'
                   END)
```